# Does a experiment measured in free fall here on earth and inside a black hole gives the same result?

Tags: gravity, atomic-physics, equivalence-principle, free-fall, tidal-effect

According to Einstein equivalence principle observer in free fall measure the same thing in experiment made in their laboratory frame.

Let us  take for example the probability $P$ of an hydrogen atom (assumed as a point) in a state $2p$ to transit to the state $1s$. Does that mean that the probability $P$ is the same for an experiment made in free fall  here an earth and for a experiment made  in free fall inside a black hole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as the size of the hydrogen atom is small compared to the radii of curvature of spacetime. If not, there will be tidal effects that change the effective potential. Dropping the atom into a supermassive black hole will give you seconds (as seen by the falling lab frame) of relatively normal physics.